# Problema Dropzone JS Solo funciona luego de limpiar cache del navedor

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone

tengo un problema una vez publicado en el hosting, mi dropzone js solo funciona luego de limpiar el cache del navegador, si antes no realizo esto se queda en un 10%.
[image: Se queda de esta manera y no hay forma de que avanze]

Este es mi codigo actual dentro del servidor hosting localmente me funciona sin problemas estoy usando PHP como backend

```js
let arrDocument=[];

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

let myDropzone = new Dropzone('.dropzone',{
    url:'../../assets/document',
    maxFilesize: 10,
    maxFiles: 5,
    acceptedFiles: 'application/pdf',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: 'Quitar',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    error: function(file, response) {
        // Oculta el mensaje de error
        console.log('Error: ' + response);
    }
});
```